# Android room relational database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am newbie in android room. how to relation 3 tables to database?

this from dao

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM m_mapping_inspection JOIN m_mapping_item, m_item ON m_mapping_item.childid=m_item.internalid AND m_mapping_inspection.mappingitemid = m_mapping_item.internalid WHERE m_mapping_inspection.mappinglocationid = :locationMappingId")
fun getItemUraian(locationMappingId: Int): LiveData<List<GetItemUraian>>
```

this from dataclass

```
data class GetItemUraian(

    @Embedded
    val mMappingItemEntity: MMappingItemEntity,

    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "internalid",
            entityColumn = "mappingitemid"
    )
    val mMappingInspectionEntity: MMappingInspectionEntity,

    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "childid",
            entityColumn = "internalid"
    )
    val mItemEntity: MItemEntity)
```

this from repository

```
fun getItemUraian(locationMappingId: Int): LiveData<List<GetItemUraian>> {
    Log.d("JKJK", locationMappingId.toString())
    return localDataSource.getItemUraian(locationMappingId)
}
```

this from viewmodel

```
fun getItemUraian(locationMappingId: Int) : LiveData<List<GetItemUraian>> = formSheDoverRepository.getItemUraian(locationMappingId)
```

this spinner

```
binding.spinnerItemCode.adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, it)
            binding.spinnerItemCode.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
                override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                    binding.layoutForm.removeAllViews()
                    // Memilih spinner atas
                    val selectedItem = parent?.selectedItem
                    val strArray = selectedItem.toString().split("-").toTypedArray()
                    val locationName = strArray[1]
                    val locationMappingId = strArray[0].toInt()
                    getItemUraian(locationMappingId)

                }
            }
```

this function getItemuraian

```
private fun getItemUraian(locationMappingId : Int){

    val array = ArrayList<Map<String, String>>()

    viewModel.getItemUraian(locationMappingId).observeForever {
        if(it != null){
            Log.d("KACRUT", it.toString())
            for(i in 0 until it.size) {
                val inspectionMappingId = it[i].mMappingInspectionEntity.internalid
                val uraian = it[i].mItemEntity.itemname
                val stockawal = it[i].mMappingInspectionEntity.stock
                val unit = it[i].mMappingInspectionEntity.unit
                val map = mapOf<String, String>("mappingId" to inspectionMappingId.toString(), "uraian" to uraian, "stockawal" to stockawal.toString(), "unit" to unit)
                array.add(map)
            }
            showUraian(array)
        }
    }
}
```

is this my code is correct? why my program not response in spinner on click?

Comment: Which spinner ?

Comment: Have you tried to put debugger stops to see which line doesn't run inside onItemSelected?

Comment: when I click that spinner still get the results earlier but item code already changed

Comment: Then please edit the post to make it sure what's expected and what's happening. Also, check if the code here is what is [mre]

Comment: is the data class room in accordance with my sql?